# runtime indexing with std::get

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variant

I'm trying to turn a `vector` of `variant`s into a `tuple` of `vector`s variadicly (i.e. I'd like to factor out the following code into a variadic template `std::variant<Ts...>`).

```cpp
std::vector<std::variant<float, int>> vector_of_variants;
vector_of_variants.emplace_back(1);
vector_of_variants.emplace_back(2.f);

std::tuple<std::vector<float>, std::vector<int>> result;
for (auto& el : vector_of_variants)
{
    auto index = el.index();
    std::get<index>(result).pushback(std::get<index>(el)); // error: index is runtime value
}
```

However, the line `std::get<index>(result).pushback(std::get<index>(el));` obviously won't work and I need to replace it with some `std::visit` like behaviour (i.e. generate the line `tuple_size` times and delegate at runtime).

What's the ergonomic way to do this?

---

Thanks to user17732522 I managed to get my template working https://godbolt.org/z/Geq1Kvjx9

Comment: this doesn't really make sense to me- turning a `vector` of `T` into a `tuple` of `T`. How can this work unless you know the size at compile-time? And if you know the size at compile-time, why are you using a `vector` at all? And why a `tuple`? Why not an `array`?

Comment: You have to do `std::tuple` over `std::array` because `std::vector<float>` and `std::vector<int>` are different types

Comment: oh I see now. you want to get rid of the variants. But which variant a variant is is a _runtime thing_. A tuple type is a _compile time thing_.

Comment: @user you do know the size of the `std::variant` (which determines the size of `std::tuple`) at compile time. The idea is to write a template that you can reuse across different sized `variants`

Comment: Are you looking for something specific to this specific instance of a variant with two specific types, or generalize it for any variant?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik any number of types. A fixed number would be easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have guaranteed that corresponding indices in the variants and `result` match, something like the following should work for a naive implementation. Might not be the best performance:

```
[&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
    ((index == Is ? std::get<Is>(result).push_back(std::get<Is>(el)) : void()), ...);
}(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(result)>>{});
```

You should also probably add a check for `index == std::variant_npos` in case the variant is in the invalid state. The above will ignore a variant in this state.

---

If you don't care about repeated types, you can also use `std::visit` instead:

```
std::visit([]<typename V>(V&& v){
    std::get<std::vector<std::remove_cvref_t<V>>>(result).push_back(std::forward<V>(v));
}, el);
```

This will throw if the variant is in the invalid state as `std::visit` always does. It also doesn't support `const`/`volatile`-qualified types properly, but these are unusual in a vector or variant.

Unfortunately there is no `std::visit` alternative that passes both the value of the variant as well as the type index (e.g. as a `std::integral_constant`) to the visitor. That would make it easier here if repeated types need to be distinguished.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there would be some `std::make_index_sequence` magic

Comment: The variadic lambda doesn't compile https://godbolt.org/z/bvvKdWbse

Comment: @TomHuntington Sorry, should be better now.

Comment: I should have just seen the `std::visit` solution. Woops. Thanks!

Comment: @TomHuntington In addition to your edit, it should also be `remove_cvref_t` instead of `remove_reference_t`. Otherwise it won't work with a `const` reference to a variant.